# THREE.js jsonloader multiple objects

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I need to write a multiple objects json file that can be loaded using THREE.JSONLoader.
Right now I call the JSONLoader like:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("box.json", modelLoadedCallback);
```

and then the modelLoadedCallback is like:

```
function modelLoadedCallback(geometry, materials) {
var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
...
}
```

Using this method, I was able to create and load a json but it loads as a unique big geometry.
I need to create a scene where every box is a different Mesh. How can I format the json?
All the meshes inside the json are boxes.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Are they just simple boxes? If so, just use the BoxGeometry class.

Comment: If you need to access every box separately they can be referenced through an array{ var my_objects;}inside function modelLoadedCall{my_objects.push(object);   you can then use my_objects[2].position.x = 20; moving the third box...

Comment: I'm using json format version 3, so (as far as I know) I can only specify vertices and faces, not boxes. The alternative is to use format 4 but I don't know if it is fully supported and I haven't found any specification of it

Comment: Anyway, my problem is how to "separate" every box coming from the json in order to be able to push them inside an array...

Comment: Like I said, if they are just simple boxes, just use the BoxGeometry class. No need to load any json.

Comment: I need to load from json because the model is generated from a django application using a python script. The only way I know to send the model from the server side to the webgl client side is using a json. Do you have other ways to suggest?

Comment: I think part of the answer is to use [`ObjectLoader()`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/ObjectLoader) rather than `JSONLoader`. Docs for `ObjectLoader`: "A loader for loading a JSON resource. Unlike the JSONLoader, this one make use of the .type attributes of objects to map them to their original classes."